# Layout of multiple lines footnotes

Tags: footnotes, indentation

I have a question about footnotes with LaTeX:

I would like the multi-lines footnotes to look like:

```
1 This is the first line of the very, very long footnote
     and this is the second line of the very long footnote
     and this is the third line of the very long footnote.
```

How can I accomplish this? I already checked out package footmisc but could not find working options.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count. This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!).

Answer (score 33):

With the following code in the preamble one can use the normal `\footnote` command:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{\leftskip=2em\hskip-2em\@makefnmark#1}
\makeatother
```

The footnote number will be flush with the left margin.

Comment: Wow, excellent solution without the help of any packages. Too bad the OP doesn't seem to have returned ever since.

Comment: The template I use includes a code fragment for footnote-settings:

\AtBeginDocument{%
\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{%
    \parindent 12\p@
    \noindent
    \mbox{\@makefnmark} #1}}

How do I modify it to keep the settings in principle, but add an indentation from the second line on of 1.25cm using the method as described by you?

Comment: @kuuhkuuh Open a new question, please

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/315763/footnote-indentation-1-25cm-of-multiple-lines-footnotes

Comment: +1 Still useful to me in 2024 :)

Answer (score 12):

Use the `scrextend` package (which is part of [`KOMA-script`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/)) and its `\deffootnote` macro. See section 3.14 of the `KOMA-script` manual for details. (You may also use one of the `KOMA-script` classes instead of `scrextend`.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{scrextend}
\deffootnote[1em]{1.5em}{1em}{\textsuperscript{\thefootnotemark}}

\begin{document}

\blindtext\footnote{\blindtext}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's a better solution, using `hanging` and `footmisc`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[paperheight=8cm]{geometry}
% just to reduce sample size

\usepackage{hanging}
% provides the \hangpara command

\usepackage[flushmargin]{footmisc}
% sets the footnote mark just left of the left margin border

\renewcommand{\footnotemargin}{1em}
% changes the above and sets the footnote mark just right of the left margin border.

\newcommand{\fn}[1]{\footnote{\hangpara{3em}{1} #1}}
% makes a new footnote command \fn{} with a hanging indent of 3em (hanging indent starts after the first line)

\begin{document}

Hello\fn{This is the first line of the very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very long footnote
and this is the second line of the very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very long footnote
and this is the third line of the very long footnote.} 
World\fn{This is the first line of the very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very long footnote
and this is the second line of the very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very long footnote
and this is the third line of the very long footnote.}.

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot of the result]

Regarding the `\footnotemargin`: This setting works for one- and two-digit footnote marks. If you only have one-digit marks, `{0.5em}` might be better; if you have three-digit footnote marks, you might want to change this value to `{1.5em}`, otherwise the first digit will stick into the left margin.

For more details see the documentations of [`hanging`](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hanging/hanging.pdf) and [`footmisc`](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/footmisc/footmisc.pdf).

Comment: i.e. "better than my other solution". Nothing compared to egreg's.

Answer (score 1):

While this isn't perfect yet, it does the trick using `footmisc`. Can anybody help with proper paragraph indentation without the `\hspace`?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[hang]{footmisc}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\setlength{\footnotemargin}{1.3cm}

\newcommand{\fn}[1]{\footnote{\hspace{-1cm}#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
Hello.\fn{\blindtext}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

(The `minipage` is just to make the sample more compact, and the `blindtext` obviously is for the the blindtext. You'll probably have to alter the values a bit to make them suitable to your layout.)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can enforce the layout of a multiline footnote with a parbox like this:

```
\footnote{ \parbox [t] {\linewidth} {a footnote with a linebreak\\
will use the overall parindent settings of the document. 
If the footnote is too long the line will just wrap like in normal paragraph mode.
The t parameter makes sure the footnote mark is placed relative to the first line } }
```