# Footnote indent

Tags: indentation, footnotes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Layout of multiple lines footnotes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15952/layout-of-multiple-lines-footnotes)

This seems like a relatively simple request—though I can't seem to find the answer anywhere. I'm using the biblatex-chicago package and am simply trying to increase how much of an indent my footnotes have on the first line. Basically, it looks like the default is something like 1/4 in, and I'd rather it be 1/2in.

I'm currently in the process of rewriting a class file for my thesis after loosing a previous version (of the style file, not the thesis!). I could swear I was able to figure it out  only a few months ago—and moreover, I'm quite sure it didn't require any additional packages.

Comment: Thanks @lockstep for pointing me toward that thread—I was able to adapt their solution to mu purposes.

Answer (score 9):

Without using any packages, you can redefine `\@makefntext` to increase the indentation of the first line (I used `3.6em`, but you can use the length that better suits your needs):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage[paperheight=6cm,includefoot]{geometry}% just for the example
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{%
  \noindent\makebox[3.6em][r]{\@makefnmark}#1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Some text for a footnote citation\footfullcite{murray} and some text for a standard footnote\footnote{The footnote text.}
\end{document}
```

[image]