# How to align the long footnotes?

Tags: hyperref, footnotes, url

In the image attached, I am placing two urls into a single footnote. The second url is not aligned with the first one. Is there any way possible to do that?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,notitlepage,oneside]{report}

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

We also implemented few relevant density-based\footnote{\url{https://msu.edu/dingyaoh/WebpageofGUI/FusionTool.htm},\\ \url{http://www.lx.it.pt/mtf/mixturecode.zip}} and classification-based\footnote{\url{http://www.ti3.tu-harburg.de/rump/intlab/}} methods to perform a robust comparative analysis.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A manual fix of the skip. But wait for better answers too:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,notitlepage,oneside]{report}

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

We also implemented few relevant density-based\footnote{\setlength\parindent{18pt}\url{https://msu.edu/dingyaoh/WebpageofGUI/FusionTool.htm},\par \url{http://www.lx.it.pt/mtf/mixturecode.zip}} and classification-based\footnote{\url{http://www.ti3.tu-harburg.de/rump/intlab/}} methods to perform a robust comparative analysis.

Test

\end{document}
```

[image]

A second way from here : [Footnote indent](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49871/footnote-indent)

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,notitlepage,oneside]{report}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{%
  \noindent\makebox[10pt][r]{\@makefnmark}#1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}


We also implemented few relevant density-based\footnote{\setlength\parindent{10pt}\url{https://msu.edu/dingyaoh/WebpageofGUI/FusionTool.htm},\par \url{http://www.lx.it.pt/mtf/mixturecode.zip}} and classification-based\footnote{\url{http://www.ti3.tu-harburg.de/rump/intlab/}} methods to perform a robust comparative analysis.

Test


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To typeset URLs in footnotes, it's best to go the `\urldef` route that's mentioned in section 2 of the user guide of the `url` package. Incidentally, I can't see why the two URLs in footnote 1 should be aligned relative to each other.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,notitlepage,oneside]{report}
\setlength\textheight{3cm}  % just for this example
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\urldef{\urlA}\url{https://msu.edu/dingyaoh/WebpageofGUI/FusionTool.htm}
\urldef{\urlB}\url{http://www.lx.it.pt/mtf/mixturecode.zip}
\urldef{\urlC}\url{http://www.ti3.tu-harburg.de/rump/intlab/}
\usepackage[colorlinks,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
We also implemented a few relevant density-based\footnote{See \urlA\ and \urlB} 
and classification-based\footnote{\urlC} methods to perform 
a robust comparative analysis.
\end{document}
```