# \raggedright in footnotes with hanging indent

Tags: horizontal-alignment, footnotes, indentation

[This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24370/9077) to [Layout of multiple lines footnotes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15952/layout-of-multiple-lines-footnotes) shows how to get hanging indent in footnotes (extremely ugly if you ask me, but the editors want what the editors want).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
    \renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{\leftskip=2em\hskip-2em\@makefnmark#1}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]\footnote{\lipsum[2]}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Now I also need to make my footnotes ragged right. I've tried to just add `\raggedright` to the code above: `{\leftskip=2em\hskip-2em\raggedright\@makefnmark#1}`, or to use `footmisc` by adding `\renewcommand{\footnotelayout}{\raggedright}`. Neither approach gives ragged right footnotes with hanging indents. How can I get it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
    \renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{\raggedright\leftskip=2em\hskip-2em\@makefnmark#1}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\null\vfill% just for the example

\lipsum*[1]\footnote{\lipsum[2]}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or, using `ragged2e`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
    \renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{\RaggedRight\leftskip=2em\hskip-2em\@makefnmark#1}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\null\vfill% just for the example

\lipsum*[1]\footnote{\lipsum[2]}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That was the only place I didn't put it after all other placements failed ... *sigh*.