# Footnote of multiple lines: alignment of equations

Tags: horizontal-alignment, footnotes, indentation

I'm trying to create a footnote with multiple (3) lines with an equation in each line. I would like it look something like this:

```
Text¹
--------------------
¹ Footnotetext A=B
           and C=D
           but E \neq F
```

I already tried out the footmisc package (maybe not good enough) and played around with the approaches in: [Layout of multiple lines footnotes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15952/layout-of-multiple-lines-footnotes) and [Footnote indentation 1.25cm of multiple lines footnotes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/315763/footnote-indentation-1-25cm-of-multiple-lines-footnotes?newreg=de9bed63815146c7b64543af8f417d73).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A TABstack can help, since its width is not a complete line, but only the content width.  To make the text flow properly, the row 1 entry for column 1 has to be wider than the other column-1 entries.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine,amsmath,lipsum}
\TABstackMath
\textheight2.5in% FOR THIS MWE ONLY
\strutlongstacks{T}
\begin{document}
Here is a reference%
\footnote{
Footnote with \alignLongunderstack{%
  \text{enough text} && A=&B\\ \text{and} && CC =& D\\ \text{but not} && E\neq& F}
}
and here is another%
\footnote{\lipsum[1]}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `tabstackengine` is really universal LaTeX tool :) (+1)